# Kafka Command - Offset and Consumer Details

Tags: apache-kafka

I would like the details associated with a Kafka Topic.Is there a Kafka command to list kafka partitions , offset and associated consumer details?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this per consumer group. If you want to filter by topic try using the consumer offset checker tool:

> `bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.ConsumerOffsetChecker`

You can also use the recommended consumer group command (it currently does not offer topic filtering):

> `bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh`

References: [here](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#basic_ops_consumer_lag) and [here](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#basic_ops_consumer_group).

Comment: Topic filtering is included in the much enhanced 0.11 version of bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh

Comment: @HansJespersen There is a `--topic` option in the most recent version but it can be used only for deletion or resetting offsets, but not for describing offsets (the option that probably would help with the question above).

Comment: Agreed @vahid. I thought you could just leave off the --execute option and it would print the current data and the reset plan without executing. If that doesn't work it's necessary to use a combination of bin/kafka-topics.sh --list and bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe and  consumer-groups.sh to get all the data